# How can I connect Python with Amazon through EDI?

Tags: python, edi, amazonsellercentral

I've been meaning to register a lot of orders for Amazon, but I need to automate it. I've read a few things about this EDI concept Amazon works with, but I've no clue as to where to start or how to even connect that with Python. I'd be grateful if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: Have you seen this https://blog.logicbroker.com/blog/2016/04/22/amazon-vendor-central-api

Answer (score 1):

You can use bots (http://bots.sourceforge.net/en/about_features.shtml).  It's a free (as in beer) EDI translator written in Python.  You might need to connect it with a communication package, but there's also open source options for that as well.